# iPhone SDK - Table view, error with spaces

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have little knowledge with the iPhone SKD (don't even know what code it is objective c?). I have so far got a table view working, and then showing content on another nib file once a row clicked.

I have elseif statements for each row, telling them to load a nib file inside the ViewController. However, One row is causing a problem, it crases the app.

```
else if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"ASCII Characters"])
    {
        Asciicharacters *asciicharacters = [[Asciicharacters alloc] initWithNibName:@"ASCII Characters" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:asciicharacters animated:YES];
        [asciicharacters release];

    }
```

Here is an image of the debugger console:
[image]

I don't what to do, there is no errors displaying at all. It just crashes the app, if that row is clicked (both on simulator and iPhone). I think is't something to do with the spaces with in the name. This is the only row that has a space. But I need a space otherwise it would look silly. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you running a debug build? (This is most likely why you're not getting any errors.) Simply select "Build and Debug" from the Build menu in Xcode.

Comment: @middaparka, please see my edit with an image of the debugger console.

Comment: I highly recommend you learn more about iOS programming before proceeding: you're going to have dozens of questions that you won't be able to ask in a way that results in a useful answer in your ignorance. You being able to phrase questions in a way that gets any answers and you won't be able to understand the answers you get. You'll just end up wasting everyone's time, including your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the line

```
   Asciicharacters *asciicharacters = [[Asciicharacters alloc] initWithNibName:@"ASCII Characters" bundle:nil];
```

with

```
   Asciicharacters *asciicharacters = [[Asciicharacters alloc] initWithNibName:@"Asciicharacters" bundle:nil];
```

then only it works as with rule of objective C

Answer (score 0):

From the debug dump, it's clear that it simply can't find the NIB file named "ASCII Characters".

If this is happening on both the simulator and the device it's unlikely to be a case sensitivity issue (bearing in mind the fact that iOS devices use a case sensitive file system, whereas (depending on the format) your Mac OS X drive probably isn't case sensitive). As such, I presume the file is simply missing.

Have you checked the relevant directory tree outside of Xcode to ensure that the file is there?